# Cargar página aspx por partes

Tags: javascript, vb.net, aspx

Tengo un pagina hecha en aspx que se carga usando métodos que hacen varias consultas que demoran mucho. Entonces la idea es cargar la pagina por partes. Las partes están una debajo de otra, así que se debería cargar de arriba a abajo, dependiendo del scroll. Cuando llegue a una posición debería llamar a un método que esta en aspx.vb para cargar los datos de esa parte.
Esto es una simulación del código que esta en la página aspx y como funciona con JavaScript que lanza un alert cuando se llega a un div.

https://codepen.io/wcorpus/pen/porJOgK

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.